# Unit Testing HttpContext.GetOwinContext()

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, owin

I just started working on creating unit test for our codes. We're using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Owin middleware for our authentication and other data and user database operation.

So to start we have several controllers and based controller. On the based controller we have added the common codes like `UserManager`, `RoleManager`, etc.. These codes uses the `HttpContext.GetOwinContext`. When implementing a Unit test on one of the controller I'm required to create a unit test of the base controller which I'm currently struggling to do.

The codes would look like this:

```
protected IAuditRepository Audit
{
    get { return _audit ?? (_audit = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAuditRepository>()); }
}

protected UserManager UserManager
{
    get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager>(); }
}
```

So I have research on how to test HttpContext.GetOwinContext however, most of the things I see was not clear and does not provide much information for me to be able create a test.

I have tried to use Moq successfully for Dependency Injection however I was not able in HttpContext. Please can anyone put me in the right path oh how to test these kind of codes?

Comment: What are you trying to test exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, unit testing helps you refactoring your code.

You have arrived to a point that you see that your code is coupled , and you depends on HttpContext (breath slowly, the enemy is in front of you, but you will defeat him soon and smoothly)

Now you have a hint about how to refactor it. Make *UserManager* a dependency  and inject it in the constructor of the controllers.

Then, you will be able to mock it, and will end up whit a less coupled solution.

Also you will see soon that AuditManager is beign retrieved with Service Locator. That will get you runtime errors pain. A better approach will be to inject it too.

That's part of the magic of unit testing!

```
public class CustomController:BaseController /*Maybe you dont need BaseController anymore if it only provides you dependencies*/
{  
    protected UserManager _userManager{get;} //equals to readonly
    protected AuditManager _auditManager {get;} //equals to readonly

   public CustomController(IAuditManager auditManager,UserManager userManager)
   {
       _userManager=userManager;
       _auditManager=auditManager;
   }

}



//Unit test
[Test]
public void CustomController_WithMockedUserManager_IsAbleToTest()
{
      CustomController = new CustomController( yourMockedUserManager, yourMockedAuditManager);
     //Asserts...etc

}
```